# Instagram: access user json data by Python script

Tags: python, json, python-requests, instagram

I'm new with Python and I'm trying to extract my account's json using:
https://www.instagram.com/my_username/?__a=1
and
https://www.instagram.com/my_username/channel/?__a=1

These two links are working on Chrome browser but using a Python script I am always redirected to the login page instead get the JSON with user details.
Why?

This is the Python script:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/username/channel/?__a=1")
print(r.text)
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add auth.
like in this example taken from here https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

>>> url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
>>> auth = OAuth1('YOUR_APP_KEY', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
...               'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN', 'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET')

>>> requests.get(url, auth=auth)
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Not bad way, but she need to get API keys.

Comment: Exactly, directly from the browser I don't need it, the link above is sufficient